# mock SoapClient response from local XML

Tags: php, soap, mocking, phpunit

I would like to mock the response of a \SoapClient with XML from a file.

How can i create a stdClass object just as the SoapClient returns from a file.

The client already wraps the SoapClient, so can easily mock the response.

My mock is like this:

```
$soapClient->expects($this->once())
            ->method('call')
            ->will(
                $this->returnValue(
                    simplexml_load_string(
                        file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../Resources/file.xml')
                    )
                )
            );
```

But this returns SimpleXml and not stdClass.

**Update:**
The proposed json_encode / json_decode hack doesnt seem to handle attributes as the SoapClient returns them:

SoapClient:

```
object(stdClass)[4571]
  public 'Lang' => string 'de' (length=2)
  public 'Success' => boolean true
```

Hack:

```
  object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  object(stdClass)#30 (2) {
    ["Lang"]=>
    string(2) "de"
    ["Success"]=>
    string(4) "true"
```

Comment: try this: `$my_std_class = json_decode(json_encode($my_simplexmlelement));`

Answer (score 2):

As Alex Blex said, you must mock `__doRequest`.

See PHP's sources:

1. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f2fd51cb802cec2175a7b92d69c3306615ca29a4/ext/soap/soap.c#L2676
2. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/38c337f22eff21ae4123ce1d4354154ee8c63983/ext/soap/php_packet_soap.c#L24

`do_request` calls "__doRequest" on your SoapClient instance. And it's result then passed to `parse_packet_soap`, which then parses xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can json encode/decode SimpleXml as following:

```
$soapClient->expects($this->once())
        ->method('call')
        ->will(
            $this->returnValue(
                json_decode(json_encode(
                    simplexml_load_string(
                        file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../Resources/file.xml')
                    )
                ))
            )
        );
```

But I would advise to explicitly define the canned response as a php class.

Comment: that doesnt seem to handle attributes the same as in the SoapClients answer, i tested it and added the results

Comment: Ah, I see. You put the server response to the xml file, not the expected result. In this case you'd better mock [`SoapClient::__doRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php) method.

Comment: yes this could work. or i serialize the returned object to a file and mock the php object with unserialize

Comment: all the findings went into this bundle: https://github.com/freshcells/soap-client-bundle

Answer (score 1):

I've used Alex Blex and gaRex suggestions to mock __doRequest method.
It worked. I am enclosing example code.

```
    $localXml = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/localResponse.xml');
    $wsdl = 'https://*******.com/path/to/wsdlV5?WSDL';

    $soapClientMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\SoapClient::class)
        ->setConstructorArgs([$wsdl])
        ->setMethods(['__doRequest'])
        ->getMock();

    $soapClientMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('__doRequest')->will($this->returnValue($localXml));

    $result = $soapClientMock->__call('Function', []);
```